Share same module under two different routes in NestJs
Context: I have the following modules in my nestjs app. Which have just the boilerplate code. These modules were generated using command nest g resource resourceName.

CatModule
DogModule
FoodModule

Issue: Nestjs is not allowing to share the FoodModule for two distinct routes. I was under the impression that it can be achieved using RouterModule.register(). But nestjs is only registering the routes /food for DogModule and not for CatModule.
New Understanding: Which ever module comes last in the RouterModule is able to have /food routes
Outcome: I want to achieve the following routing:

/cats/food
/dogs/food

Such that both /cats and /dogs route can access /food routes.
Code: I have use the below code to try achieve my outcome but it doesn't work:

app.module.ts
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AppController } from "./app.controller";
import { AppService } from "./app.service";
import { CatsModule } from "./cats/cats.module";
import { DogsModule } from "./dogs/dogs.module";
import { RouterModule } from "@nestjs/core";
import { FoodModule } from "./food/food.module";

@Module({
  imports: [
    CatsModule,
    DogsModule,
    FoodModule,

    RouterModule.register([
      {
        path: "cats",
        module: CatsModule,
        children: [
          {
            path: "/food",
            module: FoodModule,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: "dogs",
        module: DogsModule,
        children: [
          {
            path: "/food",
            module: FoodModule,
          },
        ],
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}


cats.module.ts
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { CatsService } from "./cats.service";
import { CatsController } from "./cats.controller";
import { FoodModule } from "src/food/food.module";

@Module({
  imports: [FoodModule],
  controllers: [CatsController],
  providers: [CatsService],
})
export class CatsModule {}


dogs.module.ts
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { DogsService } from "./dogs.service";
import { DogsController } from "./dogs.controller";
import { FoodModule } from "src/food/food.module";

@Module({
  imports: [FoodModule],
  controllers: [DogsController],
  providers: [DogsService],
})
export class DogsModule {}


Logs from the console, this will show all the routes registered for this app
[3:39:16 PM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[3:39:16 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +6ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] CatsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] FoodModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] DogsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] RouterModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +2ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] CatsController {/cats}: +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/cats, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/cats, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/cats/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/cats/:id, PATCH} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/cats/:id, DELETE} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] FoodController {/dogs/food}: +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs/food, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs/food, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs/food/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs/food/:id, PATCH} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs/food/:id, DELETE} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] DogsController {/dogs}: +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs/:id, PATCH} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/dogs/:id, DELETE} route +0ms
[Nest] 12478  - 07/31/2024, 3:39:16 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +1ms




You can create an abstract controller that will have those methods and then extend it.
Something along the lines:
export abstract class FoodController {
  @Get('/food')
  food(){
    return 'tasty!'
  }
}
@Controller('/cats')
export class CatsController extends FoodController {}

Adjust the abstract controller to your needs
